# Fill object from async function callback Observer?

Tags: typescript, observable

I have class A:

```
class A {
   public getHeader() {
        return {
          'name': this.getName()
        }
   }

   public  getName() {
         this.teacherClass.getTeachers().subscribe((data) => {
             // return name here;
         });
   }
}
```

Problem is that when I call method: `A.getHeader()` it returns filled object with name property as empty, cause Observer `A.getName()` still does not return data from server.

How to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use subscribe in this case. you need return observable. This is how asynchronous operations work

```
class A {
   public getHeader() {
        return {
          'name': this.getName()
        }
   }

   public  getName() {
         this.teacherClass.getTeachers();
   }
}
```

then

```
let a = new A();
a.getHeader().subscribe(data => {
   // make your assignment
});
```

Comment: In this case I await when I get response, then I continue execution of code. Can I use this as async and change property object only when get response?

Comment: I couldn't understand your last question. can you elaborate it? if you can provide example?